# My bootable usb doesn't show up as an option in the boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I followed [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) guide, and my usb does not show up as an option in the boot menu. This is what my boot drive looks like. [Boot Drive Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJx7h.png)

Comment: Thank you, A reinstall fixed that, but now there is another problem. When I go to install ubuntu (After I have booted it up) There is an option to get rid of everything on my hard drive, or "Something else" (When I click on that, it shows me a list of partitions, and I don't want to mess with that with risk of messing up my windows install. There is no option to install Ubuntu alongside windows, which is what I want to do. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

How much time has Rufus take to copy everything to the drive? Have you tried mounting the ISO you've downloaded? I ask this because the copy haven't gone well: it should be more folders and files into your boot drive.

So try to [verify](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify) the image you have downloaded, and if it looks okay try again using another flash drive. If the verification show an SHA mismatch, just re-download the ISO and all should be fine.